# How to create custom previous and skip media element controls

Tags: c#, xaml

I am currently busy with creating a media player using Windows Universal Application development for Windows 10. I want to make my own custom controls, but I do not know how to create the skip and previous buttons which will skip to the next song or go back to the previous played song. I am using a "ListView" as my playlist.

Any help would be appreciated with the C# code needed to implement these 2 buttons!

Comment: Have you been sucessful in creating other buttons? What's the code you'ver tried so far?

Comment: I have coded all my other buttons and they work fine, I have been searching for code for the 2 buttons in question, but I haven't found anything yet. I don't know which code to use to implement what I want the buttons to do.